# htaccess redirection for positional parameter to base url

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

If URL contains a special parameter (URL contains `Email` in the parameter) redirect to the base URL of the page without any parameters.

For example:

```
http://example.com/accounts/daily/ybk/?Email=redacted@example.com
```

to

```
http://example.com/accounts/daily/ybk/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to match the query string, you'll need to use a `RewriteCond` (mod_rewrite) directive and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. For example, in your root `.htaccess` file try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Email=
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

For all URLs that contain `Email=` anywhere in the query string, 301 redirect to the same URL less the query string.

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution removes the query string from the redirected URL. Alternatively, you can use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+.

If you've previously tested with erroneous 301s then make sure you clear your browser cache.

**UPDATE:** For the specific URL stated (including `Email=` at the *start* of the query string):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Email=
RewriteRule ^(accounts/daily/ybk/)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use the following for the RewriteRule, `RewriteRule  ^ - [L,QSD]`. As you say, requires Apache v2.4. Only really relevant for high volumes of requests.

Comment: @Unbeliever Although the OP appears to require an _external redirect_ - presumably to canonicalize the request. Removing the query string on an internal rewrite would seem to be unnecessary (assuming the script is able to simply ignore the `Email` parameter).

Comment: you are correct, I missed the [R=301] from the rewrite flags, which is required to keep it the same as your post. Looking at the original question, it's unclear as to whether it needs to be an external redirect or not.

Comment: @w3dk The above rule works. but in my case can we Implement this rule only for specific URL. Some specific URL comes with Email parameter, not all URL

Comment: I've updated my answer for the specific URL in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The `mod_rewrite` module should be able to help you out. You write the conditions and your rewrite rules into the .htaccess file.

Reference: [Using .htaccess rewrite rules](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Comment: You can't match the _query string_ with the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ - this matches the URL-path only (which notably excludes the query string). But neither would this _remove_ the query string from the request. Unfortunately the resource you link to doesn't appear to cover query strings?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. Removed erroneous code.